# Unable to use vmod std in Varnish 3.0.0 under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

I want to `import std;` and do some `std.syslog`. However, when I restart varnish, the VCC compiler fails:

```
$ sudo service varnish restart
 * Stopping HTTP accelerator varnishd                                [ OK ] 
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd                                [fail] 
SMA.s0: max size 2048 MB.
Message from VCC-compiler:
Could not load module std
        /usr/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_std.so
        /usr/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_std.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
('input' Line 15 Pos 8)
import std;
-------###-

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and my varnish version:

```
$ varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-3.0.0 revision cbf1284)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```

Isn't `std` a built-in VMOD? How can I solve this? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:** I managed to upgrade Varnish to 3.0.3 by following the instructions on their official website. However, I still don't understand why `std` is not there in 3.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest source version 3.0.3 of Varnish and **compile it**. After installing, `locate libvmod_std.so` to confirm that this module is also installed. Then you can start the varnish to check it with your new vcl with `import std;`. For debugging you can add `-d -d` option in the varnish startup defaults in file `/etc/default/varnish`. Check `man vmod_std` for more detail on varnish standard module. It is working fine for me for this version.

Installation by default put the vcl file under `/usr/local/etc/varnish` and binaries under `/usr/local/bin/varnish*` and varnishd can be found in `/usr/bin/`. You need to change the following in the init.d startup file `/etc/init.d/varnish` because it is different from the installation by apt-get.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/varnishd
```

Also change the vcl file path in the `/etc/default/varnish` like

```
-f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Now, you should be able to start and stop the newly compiled varnish like you used varnish installed via apt-get.

Comment: Will self-compiled version works seamlessly with Ubuntu? Since I have already installed Varnish through `apt-get`, I'm afraid something will be broken.

Comment: Yes it will work seamlessly as I am using it too. Just remove the varnish with `apt-get remove varnish` before compiling it. Compilation is pretty standard. You just need to follow the step mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I let the compiled varnish take over the apt-get one, so that my service will not be interrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please upgrade your varnish on your machine with this command:

```
aptitude upgrade varnish
```

It should fix the problem. If not, please comment and will try to find some other fix.

Comment: Cannot upgrade it in this way. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 so I suppose 3.0.0 is the latest version in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to upgrade Varnish to 3.0.3 by following the instructions on the official website: https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/ubuntu

To use the varnish-cache.org repository, do the following

1. `curl http://repo.varnish-cache.org/debian/GPG-key.txt | sudo apt-key add -`
2. `echo "deb http://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/ lucid varnish-3.0" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install varnish`

They only provide packages for Ubuntu's LTS releases, not all the intermediate releases. So it says `lucid` but works fine with `oneric` (11.10).

After upgrading Varnish to 3.0.3, I can `sudo service varnish reload` and `import std;` works fine now.